# Problem with IE11 and Mozilla Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer

[image]We have agenda functionality running in SalesForce Enterprise but it seems only functioning in Chrome. It is definitely not working in Firefox Mozilla and IE11.
I have both browsers configured according to the SalesForce instruction but it  does not help me. I attach the screen with Chrome and IE different browsers. I just added a screen after pressing F12

[image: Chrome]

[image: IE11]

Comment: Press F12 in IE, see what console errors pop up. We can't really help you from just a couple screenshots.

Comment: Can you add a little bit of code just to see how you've set it up and  what it looks like.

Comment: Just added a screen after pressing F12